# How to use kivymd custom class in different kivymd app

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

this is my easymd.py

```
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard 

from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty, StringProperty,ColorProperty



kv = '''

<SegmentedControl>:

    id: segment_panel

    size_hint_y: None

    height: self.minimum_height   

    md_bg_color:'red' if not self.segment_color else self.segment_color

<SegmentedControlItem>:

    id: s1

    text: ''

    color: 'black'

    size_hint_y: None

    height: self.minimum_height

    elevation: 0

    md_bg_color:'red'

    padding:20

        

    MDLabel:

        id: l1

        size_hint_y: None

        text: s1.text

        halign: 'center'

        color: s1.color

        pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}

        height: self.texture_size[1]

        

    MDSeparator:

        id: divider

        orientation: 'vertical'

        size_hint_y: None

        height: s1.height * 0.5

        pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}

        

'''

class SegmentedControl(MDCard):

        segment_color = ColorProperty(None)        

        pass



class SegmentedControlItem(MDCard):

        segment_color = ColorProperty(None)        

        active = BooleanProperty(True)

        pass
```

and this is my simple kivymd app. but It’s Just showing a blank MDCard. But i implemented so many things in my easymd's custom classes. You can see above

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

from easymd import SegmentedControl,SegmentedControlItem



kv = '''



MDBoxLayout:

    orientation: 'vertical'

    md_bg_color:'pink'

    padding:20

    SegmentedControl:

        SegmentedControlItem:

            text:'Hello'





'''

class  Segment(SegmentedControl,SegmentedControlItem):

    '''implementing Segment'''

    

class SegmentSwapApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        return Builder.load_string(kv)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    SegmentSwapApp().run()
```

i want to use custom classes from my easymd.py
But when i import classes and use them i only get a blank MDCard.I'm trying to find a solution but I'm unable. And also one thing to mention that i only make my custom class to be able to use the SegmentedControlItem under the SegmentedControl.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined rules for the `SegmentedControlItem` in your `kv` string in the `easymd.py` file, but you haven't done anything with that `kv` string. You can fix that by also importing that `kv` string and then loading it, like this:

```
from easymd import kv as kv3
Builder.load_string(kv3)
```